# Admission to Ph.D. program at U.S. university without guaranteed funding

Tags: phd, funding, united-states

Recently I got admission from one U.S. university for my Ph.D. study, and they offered me a kind of scholarship that only covers my tuition fee. When I asked them about other funding possibilities such as RA or TA positions, they said that at this point they are not offering any RA or TA positions to any incoming students, only when you arrived at university, you can find one by yourself.

**My question is whether this situation is common in U.S. universities.** I have heard that some students can get an assistant-ship even before attending the Ph.D. program.  Although I have an admission letter in my hand, without enough funding for my future study I really do not what to do. **Therefore I desperately need suggestions from people who have been through this and have experience.**

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I'm not sure which quantifier you are talking about --- I thought that my edit had preserved meaning and just cleaned up grammar.  Please feel free to undo anything that you feel changed meaning.

Comment: @jakebeal: The OP wrote (in boldface): "my question is whether this situation is common in every US university".

Comment: Ah: I see "common" and "every" as conflicting with one another, and think the question is really about "common"---the OP doesn't seem interested in whether it's a universal experience, but rather whether it is a frequent situation and thus how to approach it.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Like I said, I don't think I changed the meaning, but please feel free to undo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way you are asking the question, the answer is a clear **no**: this is not common at every university, certainly not in every department at every university.  In my department (mathematics, UGA) to the best of my knowledge we have not had -- say for the last decade -- any PhD students without funding (occasionally from an outside source) that is sufficient for them to live on (albeit less than lavishly).  This situation is quite common in mathematics departments in the United States, and I think it is similar in other STEM fields.  In the social sciences and humanities, funding is distinctly more scarce, but certainly *many* entering PhD students get funding in these areas.

You ask for advice.  To get good advice you should speak to someone who knows more about your situation.  This advice is centered on the situation in mathematics, but nevertheless I think it is worth hearing: **I would think at least twice before entering a PhD program that was not committed to supporting me.**  The academic job market is very tight right now, but unevenly so: it contracts severely at every career stage, so that the majority of people who had a lot of success getting placed at one stage find themselves having more difficulties with the next.  Not just anybody gets funding for a PhD program: the resources need to be there, and you need to be (in the judgment of the admissions committee) worthy of them.  However, it is not nearly as hard to get student funding as it is to land any kind of post-PhD academic position (tenure-track or otherwise: actually, in many cases it is harder to land a research postdoc than a tenure track teaching job).

If you have a very specific plan -- worked out with at least one faculty member in the program -- for your success in that graduate program, then maybe things can work out well for you even without advanced funding.  Short of that: depleting your own financial resources to fund your graduate career is certainly, on average, a poor investment.  Please think carefully before you do this.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I am really appreciate that, another question is that do you think it is appropriate to contact faculty member in the program, especially my future adviser regarding the source of more funding possibilities..

Comment: @Daniel: Absolutely yes.  If there is a faculty member in the program who will be your advisor if you enroll, then you should talk to them about the funding situation.  Since they've made an offer to you, the ball is in your court and you should not hesitate to ask "tough questions".  E.g. I would certainly ask about the funding situation for other students of the advisor and what s/he anticipates in terms of future funding.  Be upfront: your reasons will be understandable to all.

Comment: One more data point: As far as I know, my department (mathematics at the University of Michigan) never admits Ph.D. students without offering funding unless we know (usually from their application) that they have adequate funding from some other source.  This was certainly the policy when I headed the graduate admissions committee, and I believe it remains the policy.

Comment: I know of several programs that regularly give out completely unfunded offers, and it seems to be fairly common in economics to give out a significant amounts of offers that don't include first-year funding (but possibly guarantee funding after that). It isn't the norm, but in certain fields it definitely isn't rare.

Comment: @Roger Fan: For what it's worth, the question has been edited since I answered it.  The OP actually asked "Is this common at every US university?" As my answer reflects, it is more common in some fields and programs than others.  I'm curious though: could you give examples of economics programs at US universities with the funding structure that you describe?

Comment: I should add to this (excellent!) answer by pointing out that in fields where funding is more scarce, the "return on investment" if you exit academia with a PhD tends to be lower. Consider not only your finances during the PhD, but also what you want to do when you finish. If you have little intention of continuing in academia, a "non-STEM" PhD may not pay for itself over time *even if* you get funding. That said, research is fun – and if you get paid enough to live on, that makes the opportunity cost a lot easier to swallow than if you are draining your savings.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark UCLA (look for the "unfunded 1st year" comments in [these gradcafe results](http://thegradcafe.com/survey/index.php?q=economics+ucla&t=a&o=&pp=25)) and Brown (see [this post](http://www.urch.com/forums/phd-economics/153541-2015-application-sweat-thread-72.html#post990709) for details) are two examples off the top of my head. I can confirm those schools because I know people who have gotten those offers, but a quick google turns up reports of those kinds of offers at quite a few schools (including several top ones).

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I think there's a couple reasons for this, though I'm not certain of any of them. One is that it's very uncommon for 1st-year econ students to TA, unlike many other fields. Another is that many econ programs have large cohorts and relatively high attrition rates (at least relative to what I'm familiar with), so they lose quite a few students after the first year.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Brown's [site](http://www.brown.edu/academics/economics/faqs) also apparently discusses their MA track PhD offer. "The MA students do not receive financial support from Brown University or the department and have to pay tuition. Upon successful completion of the first-year courses and the PhD core exam, they are guaranteed admission into the second year of the PhD program with a fellowship and a tuition waiver."

Comment: @Roger: Thanks, that's very helpful.  The fact that the students are "MA track" makes some difference...but it is interesting how strongly their own offer letters emphasize that this is just a technicality.  It's also strange that an Ivy League school found its way to a funding structure that is less generous than most state universities.  Perhaps, being economists, they have a clearer understanding of the incentives and financial structure than most?!?